# Similar class in iOS for java class 'SecretKeySpec'

Tags: ios

I wanted to generate secret key from set of characters for AES encryption

{ 'a', '/', '5', '0', '0', '2', '*', 'l', '+', 'O', '&','@', 'b', '~', '_', '$' }

```
in Java they are generating 'SecretKeySpec' like : 

private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = 
            new byte[] { 'a', '/', '5', '0', '0', '2', '*', 'l', '+', 'O', '&','@', 'b', '~', '_', '$' };

//Generate Secret Key
    private static 

 generateKey() throws Exception {
        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
    }
```

now i need to obtain a key in iOS which is identical to the Java one so that my encrypted password is same in both the case

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. Each time when I run the code the key value remains same for the given set of characters.

```
  unsigned char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128] = { 'a', '/', '5', '0', '0', '2', '*', 'l', '+', 'O', '&','@', 'b', '~', '_', '$' };
```

then I converted it into string and used as the key for AES encryption.

```
 NSString* encryptedKey =   [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)keyPtr];
```

this gave me string value `a/5002*l+O&@b~_$`